# Halo and Lens flare

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, lwrp

I hope you guys are fine and doing great. I am having a problem. Halo and Lens Flare are not visible if we use Light Weight Render Pipeline(LWRP). They are visible in Builtin Render Pipe line but not in LWRP. If anybody knows the solution. please let me know. Thanks :).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently it's not very clear what your question is. Additionally people put effort into answering, so it's expected that you show some effort to solve the problem by yourself too.
PS: Unity related questions better fit in [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To your problem: I think the point of the LWRP is that it's light, some features may not be available.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Emaro . I am trying to solve the problem from last two days :(. May be some features are not available yet.